# Removing row from dataframe based on list values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tree

It's a bit complicated the scenario. Please let me start explaining:

There is a dataframe such as the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['CAROLINA GEORGE SCHOOL',['carolina','george'], ['school']],
        ['CAROLINA KINDER SCHOOL',['carolina','kinder'],['school']],
        ['GEORGE KINDER SCHOOL',['george','kinder'],['school']],
        ['CAROLINA SCHOOL',['carolina'], ['school']],
        ['GEORGE SCHOOL',['george'],['school']],
        ['GEORGE EDUCATION',['george'],['education']]
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','first','second'])

df['len'] = df['first'].str.len()
df.sort_values(by='len', inplace=True)
```

The first column corresponds to the full name, the name is broken apart into two pieces which are stored as lists in the next two columns. The idea is to find the root or most basic form of the list and get rid of it.

For instance, if we have the lists ['george','kinder'], ['carolina','george'] their parent is ['george'] because `george` is contained in both lists. In the same way, if we have the lists ['carolina','george'],['carolina','kinder'] their parent is ['carolina'].

This is the most basic scenario, there would be that the parent might be made of more than one element instead of just one.

*The idea is to find the parent and get rid of it. Not sure if a dataframe is the best approach to tackle this problem.*

The basic dataframe is as follows:

```
                     name               first       second  len
3         CAROLINA SCHOOL          [carolina]     [school]    1
4           GEORGE SCHOOL            [george]     [school]    1
5        GEORGE EDUCATION            [george]  [education]    1
0  CAROLINA GEORGE SCHOOL  [carolina, george]     [school]    2
1  CAROLINA KINDER SCHOOL  [carolina, kinder]     [school]    2
2    GEORGE KINDER SCHOOL    [george, kinder]     [school]    2
```

The expected outcome is the following:

```
                     name               first       second  len
5        GEORGE EDUCATION            [george]  [education]    1
0  CAROLINA GEORGE SCHOOL  [carolina, george]     [school]    2
1  CAROLINA KINDER SCHOOL  [carolina, kinder]     [school]    2
2    GEORGE KINDER SCHOOL    [george, kinder]     [school]    2
```

It is important to notice that `GEORGE EDUCATION` row is still there because `second` column value has a list with value `education` instead of `school`. So it is removed just the parent with the same value in the `second` column.

Thanks

Comment: what is the expected output for this `df`?

Comment: Thanks @VivekKalyanarangan. I updated the Question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort of explode the `first` column to `c1` and `c2`; then work with merging potential-parents and children-names.

Here is the working code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['CAROLINA GEORGE SCHOOL',['carolina','george'], ['school']],
        ['CAROLINA KINDER SCHOOL',['carolina','kinder'],['school']],
        ['GEORGE KINDER SCHOOL',['george','kinder'],['school']],
        ['CAROLINA SCHOOL',['carolina'], ['school']],
        ['GEORGE SCHOOL',['george'],['school']],
        ['GEORGE EDUCATION',['george'],['education']]
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','first','second'])

df['len'] = df['first'].str.len()
df.sort_values(by='len', inplace=True)
df['c1'] = df['first'].transform(lambda x: x[0])

pdf = df[df.len == 1]
cdf = df[df.len == 2]

cdf.loc[:,'c2'] = cdf['first'].transform(lambda x: x[1])

rdf = pd.concat([pdf.merge(cdf[['c1']], left_on='c1', right_on='c1', how='inner'),
                 pdf.merge(cdf[['c2']], left_on='c1', right_on='c2',how='inner')], axis=0)

print(df[~(df.c1.isin(rdf.c1) & df.len == 1)])
```

Output:

```
                     name               first    second  len        c1
0  CAROLINA GEORGE SCHOOL  [carolina, george]  [school]    2  carolina
1  CAROLINA KINDER SCHOOL  [carolina, kinder]  [school]    2  carolina
2    GEORGE KINDER SCHOOL    [george, kinder]  [school]    2    george
```

PS: In the final output, feel free to remove/ignore the extra columns

Comment: Thanks @Serial Lazer, in addition the row `['GEORGE EDUCATION',['george'],['education']]` should be kept because `second` column is different (education vs school)

Comment: You can probably just add that check in the final print statement to exclude the "education" lines?